# Toggling between WPF controls

Tags: wpf, user-interface, xaml, controls

Is there an easy way in WPF/XAML to toggle between two types of controls in the same position in a panel? I'm wondering if there are alternatives to toggling visibilities.

In my application I have several checkboxes that are used to configure a bit field (the checkboxes toggle individual bits on or off). Sometimes it is easier for the user if he is able to enter the actual field value in a textbox (such as 0x03 if the first two checkboxes are checked).

Due to layout constraints I would prefer not to have both the checkboxes and textbox visible at the same time. I want to provide a radio button that allows him to select which "view" he wants to use for editing the values.

Comment: make a custom control or user control. this is EXACTLY what wpf is best at.

Comment: Could you elaborate please? Would I put the checkboxes and textbox in the user control, and provide a public method for toggling between the two? Internally, would the toggling change visibility or something else? How could I make this custom user control generic so that I could specify which types of controls should be visible in each mode, per instance of the custom user control?

Comment: In response to Ray's answer below, another approach is doing this via ContentControl+DataTemplates (or views) if you're using MVPM or a similar architecture.  You'd have to create a PM or at least INotifyPropertyChanged/DependencyProperty to handle the toggle, but it's doable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put both means of entry (CheckBoxes/TextBox) in the same position by putting them both in a Panel (say, StackPanel) and setting the Visibility of either the set of CheckBoxes or TextBox to Collapsed.

There are several ways to accomplish this, but my preferred approach would be to DataBind the CheckBox and TextBox to their respective RadioButton's IsChecked property and use a IValueConverter to convert between the boolean and Visibility property.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ContentControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.aspx) as a placeholder.  The you can set ContentControl.Content programatically.

Comment: You wouldn't want to do this -- at least setting ContentControl.Content to a FrameworkElement.  If you were going the ContentControl route, you'd be better off using DataTemplates instead of dynamically swapping out UI in the Content property.